# Using At.JS @Mentions with Devise [Ruby on Rails 4]

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

From what I've learned while investigating this issue and creating users from scratch without devise. Is that Devise does not accept `[GET]` request, and I cannot access the user model using JSON as a result. Has anyone implemented a solution that includes `At.js` and `Devise` together? How can I connect the user model to the `@Mentions symbol` for the `JS component`?

UPDATED for changes made with the help of @Seichleon.

atwho-post.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('[data-mentionable]').atwho({
    at: "@",
    data: '<%= mentionables_path %>',
    insertTpl: '${username}',
    displayTpl: '<li data-id="${id}"><span>${username}</span></li>',
    limit: 10,
  });
```

post _form.html.erb (Waiting for data-attribute)

```
<%= f.text_area :body, maxlength: @maximum_length, id: 'body', data: {behavior: 'autocomplete'} %>
```

Comment: Devise doesn't give you the controller action you want, but it does accept GET/JSON requests. You simply have to build your own users controller to support the request you want.

Comment: Ok, I will create a json method inside of a custom devise Users_Controller.rb to fetch the users in json form.

Comment: No need for it to be a custom devise controller. Originally, there is no users controller, so make that controller your own.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things to this. First let's create an action to handle getting our users.

Add the route:

```
get 'share/users', as: :mentionables
```

Add the actual action to the controller: (in my case, the controller would be the share controller)

```
class ShareController < ApplicationController
    def users
        render json: User.all, root: false
    end
end
```

Now, whenever you visit `share/users` you should get something like this in return:

```
[  
    {  
       "id":2,
       "email":"test@2build.it",
       "name": "sergio",
       ...
    },
    ...
]
```

With this, you can setup at.js like this:

```
$('[data-mentionable]').atwho({
    at: '@',
    data: '<%= mentionables_path %>',
    insertTpl: '${name}',
    displayTpl: '<li data-id="${id}"><span>${name}</span></li>',
});
```

and with that, it should list the users based off their names.

Comment: Very nice. I will try this approach.

Comment: The drop down list doesn't appear in the _form view. I followed all of your steps and restarted the server to make sure that the assets pipeline refreshed. What data element are you using in the view for the :body attribute? You can add the line to your answer <%= f.text_area :body, maxlength: @maximum_length, id: 'body', data: {behavior: 'autocomplete'} %>, etc.

Comment: I'm getting NameError undefined local variable or method for some of the attributes inside of the share_controller.rb. Which is the result of my nested attributes linked to the user model.

Comment: I got the stream of JSON data working correctly. But, I still need the data attribute for the view.

Comment: @DanielW What data attribute? in my example, it'd as long as the form element has a data-mentionable attribute. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

Post _form.html.erb view

```
<%= f.text_area :body, maxlength: @maximum_length, id: 'body', data: {behavior: 'autocomplete'} %>
```

atwho-post.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('[data-behavior="autocomplete"]').atwho({
    at: "@",
    data: "/share/users.json",
    insertTpl: '${username}',
    displayTpl: '<li data-id="${id}"><span>${username}</span></li>',
    limit: 15,
  });
```

Comment: HOw would I highlight this in views as a link to mentioned user?